# QGIS SVG icons in print preview are showing up as white silhouettes

Tags: qgis

I have created my own SVG icons in Illustrator. They show up fine in the working QGIS map, however when I create the print preview, many, but not all of the SVG icons loose layers, and most show up as a white silhouette.

[image]